# R Create Custom Function with Group by and Mutate

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have dataset and performing `group_by` and `mutate` functions.

But having errors doing this with custom function and defined column like `Value_1` or `Value_2`.

Pls advise if I might be missing something in the custom function

Dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
Date = c("2010-10-06", "2010-10-06", "2010-10-06", "2010-10 
06", "2010-10-06", "2010-10-06", "2010-10-06", "2010-10-06"),
Region = c("Central", "Central", "Central", "Central", "North", "North", 
"North", "North"),
Value_1 = c(10, 2, 4, 12, 4, 4, 2, 15),
Value_2 = c(120, 45, 20, 20, 60, 50, 75, 80),
stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Works Fine:

```
df %>%
group_by(Date, Region) %>%
mutate(Value_3 = sum(Value_1)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Error with Custom Function:

```
test_fn <- function(dataset, Col1) {  
dataset <- dataset %>%
group_by(Date, Region) %>%
mutate(Value_3 =  sum(Col1)) %>%
ungroup()  
return(dataset)
}

df_3 <- test_fn(df, "Value_1")
```

Comment: thank you this really helped!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test_fn <- function(dataset, Col1) {  
  Col1 = sym(Col1)
  dataset <- dataset %>%
    group_by(Date, Region) %>%
    mutate(Value_3 =  sum(!!Col1)) %>%
    ungroup()  
  return(dataset)
}
```

If you change `sym(Col1)` to `enquo(Col1)` then you dont need to pass `Col1` as a string, i.e `test_fn(df, Value_1)`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this for your first half and I or someone will finish the second half of your solution. You need to learn about standard vs [non-standard evaluation](https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2016/09/27/dynamic-columnvariable-names-with-dplyr-using-standard-evaluation-functions/).

```
tfn <- function(data, col, groups) {
  temp <- data %>%
    ## this gets you to group by the variables 
    ## you need to group by in a standard evaluation way
    group_by_(.dots = groups) %>%
    ## now do a mutate with the dynamic variable name
   ## mutate_(.dots and setName(value, var name)

  temp
}

tfn(df, "Value_1", c("Date", "Region"))
```